# how can fetch data from hash nested array in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array like:

```
array = [:a, b: [:c, :d]]
 => [:a, {:b=>[:c, :d]}]
```

when i was tried array[:b] i got this error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```

how can I get :b element from this array?

Note: I don't want to use index to do that (array[1]).

Comment: Why don't you want to index an in the usual manner? Are you trying to search the array for an element that is a hash with a `:b` key?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an `array` (and not a hash) you can get an element by its index. In this example:

```
array[1]
#=> { :b => [:c, :d] }
```

Comment: thank you. but I want to get it with key not index
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I don't want to use index to do that (array[1]).

```
> array.find{|e| e.is_a?(Hash) && e.has_key?(:b)}
#=> {:b=>[:c, :d]}
```

or

```
> array.find{|e| e.has_key?(:b) rescue false}
#=> {:b=>[:c, :d]}
```

for your specific example:

```
> Hash[*array][:a][:b]
#=> [:c, :d]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the solution

```
array.last[:b]
```

in this type of array all (key: val) values will store on last element of array as a hash

for example in:

```
array = [:a, :b, c: [:d], e: [:f], g: [:h]]
 => [:a, :b, {:c=>[:d], :e=>[:f], :g=>[:h]}]
```

I can access the :c element with:

```
array.last[:c]
 => [:d]
```

or

```
array.select{|x| x.instance_of?(Hash)}.last[:c]
 => [:d]
```